# generate valid address for polkadot and bitcoin and other tokens using web3.js

Tags: web3js, bitcoin, polkadot

using below code

```
 const Web3 = require('web3');
    const apikey = "b1fdacbb-59ea-4598-96ed-......";
    const network = 'testnet'; // Change to mainnet for production
    const chainId = 97; // 97 is BSC testnet, 95 is BSC mainnet
    const node = `https://btc.getblock.io/${network}/?api_key=${apikey}`;

    const web3 = new Web3(node);
    // Generate new address and private key
    const accountTo = web3.eth.accounts.create();
 
    console.log("accountTo",accountTo);
```

I got this result

```
accountTo {
  address: '0x5201CCE42eF729a8C014D8a3A405A0c9Ad4BE545',
  privateKey: '0x6b2a84f4b9c9dc5d0dee7f68...',
  signTransaction: [Function: signTransaction],
  sign: [Function: sign],
  encrypt: [Function: encrypt]
}
```

I expect 0x5201CCE42eF729a8C014D8a3A405A0c9Ad4BE545 to be a valid bitcoin address
but wen I validate it using [bitcoin address validator](https://awebanalysis.com/en/bitcoin-address-validate/)

it say its not valid
also there's another problem, when I set wrong node like this:
const node = `https://btc2222222.getblock.io/${network}/?api_key=${apikey}`;
it returns address without any error!!!! so what's the use of node here?

how can I create valid address for bitcoin, polkadot, avax , .... using Web3.js
thanks

Comment: Have you tried using cryptocoinjs: https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/cryptocoin